# Runtime error occured while iterating over 2d vector

Tags: c++, vector

I had given a 2D board containing 'X' and 'O' (the letter O), and I want to replace all 'O' surrounded by 'X'.

Ex:

```
X X X X
X O O X
X X O X
X O X X
```

ans:

```
X X X X
X X X X
X X X X
X X X X
```

Here is my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void solve(vector<vector<char>>& board) {
        solution(board);
    }

    bool issafe(vector<vector<char>>board,int i,int j)
    {
        int R=board.size();
        int C=board[0].size();

                if (i >= 0 && i < R && j >= 0 && j < C) 
                { 
                    return true;
                }
              return false; 
    }

    void solution(vector<vector<char>>&board)
    {
        int R=board.size();
        int C=board[0].size();
        for(int i=0;i<R;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<C;j++)
            {
                if (board[i][j] == 'X') { 
                    if (issafe(board,i + 1, j) && board[i + 1][j] == 'O') { 
                        board[i + 1][j] = 'X';  
                    } 
                    if (issafe(board,i, j + 1) && board[i][j + 1] == 'O') { 
                        board[i][j + 1] = 'X'; 
                    } 
                    if (issafe(board,i - 1, j) && board[i - 1][j] == 'O') { 
                        board[i - 1][j] = 'X';  
                    } 
                    if (issafe(board,i, j - 1) && board[i][j - 1] == 'O') { 
                        board[i][j - 1] = 'X';  
                    } 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

But I got a runtime error.
I am not able to find where I am wrong, Can anybody please tell me where I am going wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Where does your debugger tell you the error occurs?

Comment: Can't see anything (seriously) wrong with that code. Are you sure the error isn't somewhere else?

Comment: Not related, but your logic is a bit faulty. If you change the board while you iterate over it, you are using new values that you've written to the board. You should probably make a new board, and swap it with the old board after you're done.

Comment: If there is one X in the entire board, won't the entire board turn to all X according to your solution? Other than that, I can't see the runtime error here.

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/150139130ae253d7).

Comment: Please include the error message.

Comment: You do have a runtime error if the number of rows is zero as `C=board[0].size();` will cause an error in that case. I was assuming that would never be true.

Comment: Yes the rows and columns are never zero.

Comment: @ChrisMM,@ciegien ,@Andrew Ray here is it error "===33== ERROR: AdressSanitizer: heap buffer overflow on address 0x608000000080 at pc  0x0000003841ba bp 0x7ffc94c3a18"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a place where the error could be occurring is at board[i+1][j] and board[i][j+1] as when i==R-1 and j==C-1, the index is out of range. I don't see any other place for runtime error to occur assuming there is always a column and row in the vector.

Maybe you could try replacing all these cases with 

For Eg. board[i+1][j]  with board.at(i+1).at(j) to firstly have automated checking by the compiler for out of range index. 

Secondly, you could try

```
 void solution(vector<vector<char>>&board)
    {
        int R=board.size();
        int C=board[0].size();
        for(int i=0;i<R;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<C;j++)
            {
                  if (board[i][j] == 'X') { 
                       if(i!=R-1 && j!=C-1)
                       {
                              if (issafe(board,i + 1, j) && board[i + 1][j] == 'O') { 
                                    board[i + 1][j] = 'X';  
                               } 
                              if (issafe(board,i, j + 1) && board[i][j + 1] == 'O') { 
                                    board[i][j + 1] = 'X'; 
                               } 
                       }
                    if (issafe(board,i - 1, j) && board[i - 1][j] == 'O') { 
                        board[i - 1][j] = 'X';  
                    } 
                    if (issafe(board,i, j - 1) && board[i][j - 1] == 'O') { 
                        board[i][j - 1] = 'X';  
                    } 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey Dhruv ,thanks for your help ,it worked absolutely fine, but can you please explain what is difference between  board[i+1][j] and  board.at(i+1).at(j)?

Comment: at() is a method in the vector class that works similarly to the square brackets with the additional functionality of checking if your index always lies in the range of your vector. If it exceeds the index range, the compiler will throw an error message.